# virtualbox - 2 host connection

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

I want to connect two hosts(ubuntu) in virtualbox by: Attached to NAT.

I set up in terminal:
- 1st host: `sudo ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0`
- 2nd host: `sudo ifconfig eth1 10.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0`

and I checked on the 1st and 2nd host:

```
ping yahoo.com   -> unknownhost
```

---

- `ping 10.0.0.1` on the first host -> ok
- `ping 10.0.0.2` on the first host -> destination host unreacheable

---

- `ping 10.0.0.1` on the second host -> destination host unreacheable
- `ping 10.0.0.2` on the second host -> ok

What did I do wrong?

---

For second host:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:B8:2F:C5  
          inet addr:10.0.0.2  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feb8:2fc5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:52 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:52 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6100 (5.9 KiB)  TX bytes:10176 (9.9 KiB)
          Base address:0xd240 Memory:f0820000-f0840000 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:C1:F8:AA  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fec1:f8aa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:37 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4774 (4.6 KiB)  TX bytes:4052 (3.9 KiB)
          Base address:0xd010 Memory:f0000000-f0020000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:100 (100.0 b)  TX bytes:100 (100.0 b)

sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4  
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Comment: why are you using NAT instead of bridged?

Comment: i want to connect this hosts using private ip(RFC 1918)

Answer (score 0):

Set up 2 seperate interfaces on each VM - One for NAT (which gives internet-acccess to the vms) and one as "[Internal Networking](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal)" for inter-VM-communication.

Your current NAT Interfaces are not able to talk with each other.

Comment: i set up on the first host: Adapter 1:NAT,Adapter 2: INERNAL NETWORK. The same on second host, what should i do next?

Comment: Nobody wants to help me?

Comment: NAT networking requires no more action - the Guests should be able to reach every network that your host can reach. For the internal network you should have a look into your guest OS for figuring out the subnet and IPs of your guest - then you should be able to communicate between guests.